# How do you replace the points on a box plot with the point's corresponding row number index?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Train_Table_Time_Power <- data.frame(
Skew = runif(250),
Crest = runif(250),
Kurt = runif(250),
Impulse = runif(250),
  TI = sample(c("0.05", "0.10", "0.15", "0.20"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I then created a box with points using the code below:

```
Crest_BoxPlot <- ggplot(Train_Table_Time_Power, aes(x = TI, y = Crest, color = TI)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = T, id=TRUE) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=19, color="red", size=2) +
  geom_jitter(shape=16, position = position_jitter(0.2), size = 0.3) +
  labs(title = "Crest_Time", x = "TI", y = "Normalized Magnitude") +
  theme_minimal() + theme_Publication()
```

I would like to somehow have the individual points of the boxplot be replaced with their row number index, however, I can't seem to figure out a way how. Could someone direct me on how to do this, if it is indeed possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `geom_text()`instead of `geom_jitter()`, but be aware that readability is limited due to the overlapping labels.

```
# add the row number as column
library(tibble)
Train_Table_Time_Power <-  rowid_to_column(Train_Table_Time_Power)

ggplot(Train_Table_Time_Power, aes(x = TI, y = Crest, color = TI, label = rowid)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = T, id=TRUE) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=19, color="red", size=2) +
  geom_text(position = position_jitter(0.2)) +
  labs(title = "Crest_Time", x = "TI", y = "Normalized Magnitude") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]